# Refactoring multiple left joins

Tags: mysql

A simplified version of my table layout is as follows:

table item

```
+----+-------+-----+
| ID | sdesc | ... |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | item1 | ... |
+----+-------+-----+
```

table itemaffectTable (call these qProps for properties with quantities)

```
+--------+---------+----------+
| itemID | affectID| quantity |
+--------+---------+----------+
|      1 |       2 |       10 | // item 1 has affect 2 for a value of 10
|      1 |       3 |        2 | // item 1 has affect 3 for a value of 2
|      2 |       1 |        5 | // item 2 gets aff 1 for 5
|      2 |       1 |        6 | // item 2 gets aff 1 for 6 which means 11 total
|      3 |       5 |        5 | 
+--------+---------+----------+
```

table itemaffectbyTable (call these bProps they're relevant when present)

```
+--------+---------+
| itemID | affbyID |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |       6 |
|      3 |       2 |
|      3 |       3 |
+--------+---------+
```

Sample output:

```
itemID  sdesc           qpropID value   bpropID
1221    a copper lantern      4     2   5
1221    a copper lantern     18     2   5
1221    a copper lantern     17    -5   5
 477    a shade              19     3   4
 477    a shade              19     3   6
```

This is incorrect in two ways.  For the first item the affectbyID 5 is repeated 3 times ... this is tolerable.  In the second case we have the affectID 19 and affect value 3 being repeated twice, this is not permissible.

Ideally I'd like to see

```
itemID  sdesc           qpropID value   bpropID
1221    a copper lantern      4     2   5
1221    a copper lantern     18     2   NULL
1221    a copper lantern     17    -5   NULL
 477    a shade              19     3   4
 477    a shade            NULL  NULL   6
```

The main problem is the repetition of the qpropIDs and values since they are additive.  If the solution repeats bpropIDs it's no big deal.

** UPDATE **

I attempted to use the FULL JOIN idea to get my results but couldn't seem to zero in.

The closest I've come to the results I want came from using sqlFiddle to get

```
select i.id, i.sdesc, iaft.affectID, iaft.amount, NULL FROM item i
    LEFT JOIN itemaffectTable iaft ON i.id=iaft.itemID
UNION
select i.id, i.sdesc, NULL, NULL, iafbt.affectbyID FROM item i
    LEFT JOIN itemaffectedbyTable iafbt ON i.id=iafbt.itemID
ORDER BY id
```

So bottom line the idea is I want to retrieve a list of items which meet the criteria of the filters and then match those items up with their associated affectID and affectbyIDs.

The original is below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, i.sdesc, iaft.affectID, iaft.amount, iafbt.affectbyID FROM item i
INNER JOIN itemwearTable iwt ON i.id=iwt.itemID 
    LEFT JOIN itemaffectTable iaft ON i.id=iaft.itemID
    LEFT JOIN itemaffectedbyTable iafbt ON i.id=iafbt.itemID
LEFT JOIN itemalignTable iat ON i.id = iat.itemID
LEFT JOIN itemgenderTable igt ON i.id = igt.itemID
LEFT JOIN itemgenreTable igrt ON i.id = igrt.itemID
LEFT JOIN itemclassTable ict ON i.id = ict.itemID
LEFT JOIN itemraceTable irt ON i.id = irt.itemID
WHERE (iat.itemID IS NULL OR iat.alignID = 1)
AND (igt.itemID IS NULL OR igt.genderID = 1)
AND (igrt.itemID IS NULL OR igrt.genreID = 1)
AND (ict.itemID IS NULL OR ict.classID = 1)
AND (irt.itemID IS NULL OR irt.raceID = 1)
AND i.minlvl <= 50
AND iwt.wearlocID=1
ORDER BY sdesc
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you are talking about. Perhaps some sample data and desired output would help. An [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) would be even better.

Comment: @Bohemian I hope the above edit will make clear my problem.  Thanks! :)

Comment: There is a bare knuckles version of the problem http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdf34/1

Comment: OK, OK, you wore me down! See my answer - it does everything you want (I hope!) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really is a strange result you're after - it's a sort of pivoted union or something.

Nevertheless, but here it is, with all the bells and whistles you asked for!

```
select id, sdesc, affectID, amount, affectbyID
from (select 
    id, sdesc, 
    if(sameid and @affectID = affectID and @amount = amount, null, affectID) as affectID,
    if(sameid and @affectID = affectID and @amount = amount, null, amount) as amount,
    @affectID := affectID,
    @amount := amount,
    if(sameid and @affectbyID = affectbyID, null, affectbyID) as affectbyID,
    @affectbyID := affectbyID
from (select
    if(@id is null, false, @id = id) as sameId,
    @id := id as id,
    sdesc, affectID, amount, affectbyID
from (select distinct
  i.id,
  i.sdesc,
  iaft.affectID,
  iaft.amount,
  iafbt.affectbyID
FROM item i
LEFT JOIN itemaffectTable iaft ON i.id=iaft.itemID
LEFT JOIN itemaffectedbyTable iafbt ON i.id=iafbt.itemID
ORDER BY 1,3,4,5
) x) y) z
```

This makes use of [User Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) to remember the previous values for columns.

The logic is reset for every new `id` value, and other columns are made null if the column (or column pair) has the same value as the previous row.

See a [live demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d499/10)

Comment: When I used this on my full data set I saw a couple of erroneous rows pop up, which I added to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68942/1.  This seems to be very very close to what I want and about 3 times faster than the union idea I noted.

Comment: I've added an `order by` that should have been there before, but what's the problem with the output? Just showing me that fiddle didn't tell me anything. I gtg now - I will look for your extra feedback and see what I can do in about 12 hours.

Comment: I'm seeing a difference between my live data and the sqfiddle.  I added a "problem" item to a new sqfiddle and your query handled it perfectly.  When I run the query on my live server I get the old, incorrect result as though the IF statements aren't executing.  This could be a configuration issue or version issue on my side with GoDaddy.  Additionally, adding DISTINCT to the first select took care of the duplicates which originally drew my attention.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here.  I believe this is what you are looking for.  In SSMS I would solve this with a Full Join, but apparently you cant do that in mysql so you need a union to combine the right and left outer joins.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-full-joins.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your expected result... it seems quite irrational to me.

Do you want to do something like, for each item, assume you get item-affect and item-affectedBy separately, and you want to combine the result in a row-based manner? i.e. row 1 of item A in first result will be put together with row 1 of item A in second result: e.g.

```
Item     Affect               Item     AffectedBy
 1         a                    1         r
 1         b                    
 2         c                    2         s
                                2         t
 3         d
                                4         u
 5         e                    5         v
 5         f                    5         w
```

You want to see something like:

```
Item    Affect    AffectedBy
1         a          r
1         b          NULL
2         c          s
2         NULL       t
3         d          NULL
4         NULL       u
5         e          v
5         f          w
```

Right?

If so, the most straight-forward way you can think of is, first make result of item-affect looks like:

```
Item     Affect   seq
 1         a        1
 1         b        2
 2         c        1 
 3         d        1
 5         e        1
 5         f        2
```

Seq column is the "rank" within group of item.
Do similar thing in item-affectedBy

Then do a full outer join on item and seq column.

I am not sure how to achieve these in MySQL, in Oracle, the way to generate the seq is something like:

```
select item_id, affect_id, rank() over (partition by item_id order by rownum) rank
from item_affect
order by item_id, rank;
```

Try to think if you can do similar thing in MySQL.

For full outer join, if it is not supported, you can always perform a union with left and right join.